# Ruby PG Gem `exec_params` vs `exec_prepared`

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

What are the differences between `Connection#exec_params` and `Connection#exec_prepared`?  It seems like they both require the same kinds of input and they both perform the same action. Why would someone choose one versus the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exec_prepared` to optimize SQL query, see [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-prepare.html).

`exec_params` lets you execute specified SQL query with binded parameters. `exec_prepared` lets you execute prepared (parsed, optimized etc) SQL query specified by its string identificator/name which you have got earlier.

If you make a lot of similar SQL select queries and difference is parameter values, you can make it effectively by preparing SQL statement once (you receive it identifier) and execute it with different parameters multiple times.